# NVD3.js line graphs fail to scale y axis to max and min values

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, nvd3.js

Building a page with multiple graphs, I've decided to use NVD3.

The problem is that NVD3 fails to find the maximum value, rendering some useless graphs.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxU8c/

```
function renderGraph(parent, data) {
    function getGraph(svgElement, data) {
        var height = 500;

        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
        chart.options({
            noData: "Not enough data to graph",
            transitionDuration: 500,
            showLegend: true,
            showXAxis: true,
            showYAxis: true,
            rightAlignYAxis: false
        });

        chart.xAxis     //Chart x-axis settings
            .axisLabel(data['x-label'])
            .tickFormat(function(d) {
                return d3.time.format('%d.%m.%Y')(new Date(+d))
            });

        chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
            .axisLabel(data['y-label'])
            .tickFormat(d3.format('.02f'))
        ;

        svgElement    //Select the <svg> element you want to render the chart in.
            .datum(data['data'])         //Populate the <svg> element with chart data...
            .call(chart);          //Finally, render the chart!

        //Update the chart when window resizes.
        nv.utils.windowResize(function() { chart.update() });
        return chart;
    }
    var svgELement = d3.select('svg#chart_'+data['code']);
    nv.addGraph(getGraph(svgELement, data));
}
```

I'm also using twitter bootstrap for layout, if it helps.

**EDIT**

following fiddle should be more useful since it contains less garbage
http://jsfiddle.net/Bh578/

the first and the seconds graphs are displaying the problem while the third is rendered accordingly to my expectations (i.e. you can see the whole line)

I have also added the useInteractiveGuideline: true option so it's more obvious that there are values outside of the visible graph area that I'd like to see on the chart too.

Comment: What do you mean `fails to find the maximum value` , by looking at the charts it looks like there might be a problem with your dataset. What exactly are you trying to achieve here??

Comment: Hi @shabeer90, `fails to find the maximum value` means that the set of values on the y axis is on some graphs singificantly smaller than of others, with no system obvious to me.
The expected behaviour was that any dataset will render graphs where the whole line is visible, but that is obviously not the case.
I have no idea what dataset problems to look for, could you give me some pointers please? It's all integers, with javascript's weak typing, representing them as strins shouldn't be a problem, right?
thank you very much

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. NVD3 isn't using the largest Y value for the axis max value. Instead, it's using a different, smaller value. All my values are Fixnum (Fixnum is a subclass of Integer). Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Values should be integers, not JSON-decoded-as-strings integers, then it works like a charm.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, just returned `Number(d.y)` for my `y` function. Saved me a lot of pain of calculating the max Y every time I updated the chart... Thank you!